# Setting path causing issues in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, path

All, I'm trying to use some code in MATLAB 2015a that works fine in 2010a but when I do it, I get errors when plotting, the routines don't work. Support told me to use resetdefaultpath, but then the code can't find my functions that are in subfolders. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: What errors do you get? You probably added functions which shadow build-in functions from MATLAB so you have to rename them.

Comment: Error using assert
Too many input arguments.

Error in matlab.graphics.shape.internal.AxesLayoutManager.getManager

Error in legendcolorbarlayout (line 19)
hManager  = matlab.graphics.shape.internal.AxesLayoutManager.getManager(hAx);

Error in matlab.graphics.illustration.Legend/setAxesImpl

Error in matlab.graphics.illustration.Legend/set.Axes_I

Error in matlab.graphics.illustration.Legend/set.Axes

Error in legend>make_legend (line 332)
leg.Axes = ha;

Error in legend (line 247)
        [h,msg] = make_legend(ha,args(arg:end),version);

Comment: No Idea what went wrong here. Can you identify which of your files causes the problem? What is the function name?

Comment: Error in plotvalrocresults (line 82)
legend('dagreader','donereader');

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything. Please try to create a [mcve] which allows us to understand and reproduce your issue.